# Android GraphView Memory Usage For Large Data Set

Tags: java, android, arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-graphview

I am relatively new at Android (to give context to my skill level).

**Summary (Question stated at the bottom):** My app uses a lot of CPU (sounds basic, sorry) and I think it is because I'm using 3000 datapoints.

**Context:** I am making an app that takes bytes from a Bluetooth LE service

```
    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
    final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    Log.i(TAG, "data"+characteristic.getValue());

    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for(byte byteChar : data)
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s", new String(data)));
        // getting cut off when longer, need to push on new line, 0A
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA,String.format("%s", new String(data)));
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In another activity, I append the data to the graph using datapoints. (displayData just displays the data I'm getting onto a textview).

```
     else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            //cnt starts at 0

            String data = intent.getStringExtra(mBluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(data); //create type:double version of data

            if(cnt == 3000) { //if graph maxes out regenerate new data
                cnt = 0; //set the count back to zero
                clearUI(); //clear textView that displays string version
                series.resetData(new DataPoint[] {new DataPoint(cnt + 1, y)});
            }
            else //if there is no need to reset the map
            {
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(cnt + 1, y), false, 3000); //append that data to the series
            }
            displayData(data, y); //display cnt, data(string), and y(double)
            cnt++;
        }
```

Using a serial port tester, sending the number "12.5" every 60ms, the graphing process works fine until I reach about 300 datapoints. After that, the app becomes laggy. Logcat states that 30-34 frames are being skipped. By 3000 datapoints, Logcat states that 62-74 frames are being skipped.

**Question:** What can I do to structure my data better and/or make the app run smoother?

Comment: profile to see where the time is really being spent....

Comment: @ifor : What does that mean? Like I said, my skill level is pretty low.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html